# type of int/string seems to be causing error

Tags: asp.net-core, f#, asp.net-core-3.1

I get the following error

`error FS0019: This constructor is applied to 0 argument(s)`

from this code

```
type Expression = Number of int | Operator of string | WhiteSpace of string

let IsNotWhiteSpace expression =
    match expression with 
    | Number | Operator -> true 
    | WhiteSpace -> false
```

I do not get any red line from this it only shows when I compile. I have run out of ideas of what could be causing this. If someone could explain this to me I would greatly appetite it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to match the int or string values in your constructors into a variable, e.g.

```
let IsNotWhiteSpace expression =
  match expression with 
  | Number n -> true 
  | Operator o -> true 
  | WhiteSpace w -> false
```

Since you don't need the values, you can also discard them using `_`

```
let IsNotWhiteSpace expression =
  match expression with 
  | Number _ | Operator _ -> true 
  | WhiteSpace _ -> false
```

Comment: Thank you, I was very confused.